# APL language compiler to IL

Tags: .net, transpiler, apl

I don't have any experience working with APL and no one in our team has, but what we have is huge code base, which must be rewritten using more modern approaches. So I am just wondering are there any compilers, which can help with producing IL code from APL code? Or any other suggestions are really welcomed, how should we approach it?

Comment: You don't *transpile* into IL. This is a process of compilation. That aside, I don't know of any compilers of APL into IL, but the language has a strongly supported implementation under constant development by Dyalog (Dyalog APL) which support many adapters to .Net and windows. Might worth looking into it.

Comment: Just read the Wikipedia article.  It even talks about a APL-to-C# translator, surely what you really want.

Comment: First, you need to make sure you are clear of what to ask. As you have a large APL code base, you might 1) convert all APL code to another language (I assume C# for .NET, which is the most popular option), or 2) compile APL code to IL, so it runs on .NET CLR. Each has its advantages and disadvantages, and might work if there are certain tools, or your team have to develop on your own. But the first step is that you need to choose from 1) and 2).

Answer (score 6):

You do not say *why* it must be rewritten. I imagine it could be any of the following reasons:

**You need to make changes and your team does not have any APL programmers.**
 There *are* APL programmers and consultants out there and more are constantly appearing. I suggest advertising your need on [an APL forum](http://www.dyalog.com/forum/) and contacting various [user groups](https://www.dyalog.com/user-groups.htm) and [application developers](https://www.dyalog.com/application-development-partners/index.htm).

**You are using an APL system from a vendor which no longer provides the needed support or you are looking to switch platform.**
 [Contact Dyalog](https://www.dyalog.com/contact-us.htm) directly as Dyalog [has much experience](https://www.dyalog.com/case-studies/index.htm) in migrating systems to the actively maintained, developed, and supported cross-platfrom Dyalog APL.

**APL is perceived as old-fashioned so you want to future-proof your system by changing to a more common language.**
 [Dyalog APL](https://www.dyalog.com/dyalog/index.htm) is a language that has been tuned and optimised for more than 30 years and has thus has evolved from classical APL2-style into a modern, multi-paradigm programming language. As Dyalog APL has [full support and integration with .NET](http://docs.dyalog.com/16.0/Dyalog%20for%20Microsoft%20Windows%20.NET%20Interface%20Guide.pdf), it is on Microsoft's official list of *.NET languages*.

**You are looking for higher performance.**
 Depending on which APL system you use, you have several options here. Just upgrading to the latest interpreter version can gain you tremendous speed-ups. A consultant may also be able to tune your APL code to increase speed. Dyalog APL [includes an on-the-fly compiler](http://docs.dyalog.com/16.0/Compiler%20User%20Guide.pdf) and now has [built-in hashing](http://help.dyalog.com/16.0/Content/Language/Defined%20Functions%20and%20Operators/Search%20Functions%20and%20Hash.htm) for faster lookups. If you restrict yourself to the functional programming subset of Dyalog APL, *dfns*, you may use the [Co-dfns Compiler](http://arcfide.github.io/Co-dfns/) to create C++ code from your APL code.

If none of these reasons apply to you, then please update your question to be more specific.

Comment: Do you have some compilers exemples ?

Comment: @WilmarArias I'm not sure what you mean. My post already links to two compilers. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @WilmarArias The [APL2C](https://www.apl2c.de) site has [a list](http://www.apl2c.de/home/Links/links.html).

Comment: Sorry I don't mean compiler I think I mean transpiler do you know any software that ttanpiles APL code to c# , Java or JavaScript? :)

Comment: @WilmarArias [*Compiling APL to JavaScript*](http://archive.vector.org.uk/art10501160) (the link at the bottom is broken, and anyway, he has migrated [to GitLib](https://gitlab.com/n9n/apl))

Answer (score 1):

There are several APL compilers out there which output different target languages, namely C, C#, Java, JavaScript, SAC, and perhaps others.  However, these compilers may be experimental, academic, or not of an expected commercial quality.  Further, the compiler may support only a subset of the language or not support newer language features (like Dfns).  Lastly, the code emitted by a compiler would be very large and may not be something one would want to maintain going forward.  Google Snake Island Research, Aaron Hsu, and Timothy Budd for more info.

One other thing to consider is that the philosophy and thinking behind APL programming may be rather (if not wildly, if not profoundly) different from that of programming in languages like C# or Java.  Have a look at Aaron Hsu's talk from 11 September 2017 which explains this rather well.  See https://video.dyalog.com/Dyalog17/?v=cpbtX0jK1z4 - Aaron's talk starts at around 2:00:00.

It would be useful to know something about the APL code in question - roughly when and for what APL system was it written, then where you'd like to go with the code - target language (Java etc.), OS, whether it should be a web application, etc.